# How to return value from unit test?

Tags: return, nunit, pipeline, testcase

I have the following problem.I have a process that is done in 3 steps:

```
Step 1 -> Step 2 ->Step 3
```

I want to be able to test all combinations.

```
Step1
Step1+Step2  
Step2
Step2+Step3
Step1+Step2+Step3
```

In order to do this i would like to be able to return something from each of my `Unit Tests`.
I do not want to create global variables and mutate them every single time.

```
class TestPipeline
{
[Testcase]
public Int Step1()
{
   ////do something
   Int outputStep1=doSomeStuff();
   return outputStep1;
}

[Testcase]
public Int Step2()
{
   Int inputStep1=Step1();
   Int outputStep2=doSomething(inputStep1);
   return outputStep2;
}
[Testcase]
public void Step3()
{
   Int inputStep2=Step2();
   Int result=doSomethingElse(inputStep2);
}
}
```

How can this be done ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that you need helper methods that you can reuse, you're most of the way there, just need to extract out the methods.

As for getting the combinations correct I'd just hard-code the combinations. It looks like your steps are sequential so there won't be such a test as Step2+Step3 because it would really be Step1+Step2+Step3.

Tests are normally data driven and having logic in the test to vary behaviour based on data with something such as [Combinatorial](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Combinatorial-Attribute) adds unwanted logic into the test.

```
class TestPipeline
{
    private int doSomeStuff()
    {
        return someStuff;
    }

    private int doSomething(int someStuff)
    {
        return something;
    }

    private int doSomethingElse(int something)
    {
        return somethingElse;
    }       

    [Testcase]
    public void Step1()
    {
       ////do something
       int outputStep1 = doSomeStuff();
       return outputStep1;
    }

    [Testcase]
    public void Step1Step2()
    {
       int inputStep1 = doSomeStuff();
       int outputStep2 = doSomething(inputStep1);
       return outputStep2;
    }

    [Testcase]
    public void Step1Step2Step3()
    {
       int inputStep1 = doSomeStuff();
       int outputStep2 = doSomething(inputStep1);
       int result = doSomethingElse(inputStep2);
    }
}
```